# Alembic - sqlalchemy initial migration

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am having a problem creating an initial migration which would automatically have tables that I've defined in my models.py by using shared Base (declarative_base).

When I enter a command:

```
alembic revision --autogenerate
```

alembic creates an empty file.

What's wrong in my configs or my approach?

project.base.py:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()
```

env.py:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))
from alembic import context
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config, pool
from logging.config import fileConfig

from project.base import Base
target_metadata = Base.metadata
def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    engine = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool)

    connection = engine.connect()
    context.configure(
        connection=connection,
        target_metadata=target_metadata
    )

    # target_metadata.reflect(engine, only=[
    #     "django_migrations",
    #     "auth_group_permissions",
    #     "django_session",
    #     "auth_user_user_permissions",
    #     "auth_user_groups",
    #     "django_admin_log",
    #     "auth_permission",
    #     "auth_user",
    #     "sysdiagrams",
    #     "django_content_type",
    #     "auth_group",
    #     "sysdiagrams",
    # ])

    try:
        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
    finally:
        connection.close()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

Sample model:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Boolean, ForeignKey, SmallInteger
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from project.base import Base


__schema__ = "Users"


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "User"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': __schema__}

    USER_CUSTOMER = 0
    USER_EMPLOYEE = 5
    USER_ADMIN = 10

    USER_TYPES = (
        (USER_CUSTOMER, u'Klient'),
        (USER_EMPLOYEE, u'Obsługa sklepu'),
        (USER_ADMIN, u'Administrator')
    )

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    email = Column(String(255))
    password = Column(String)
    date_created = Column(DateTime)
    date_updated = Column(DateTime)
    user_type = Column(SmallInteger)

    is_active = Column(Boolean)

    def __repr__(self):
        return u"<User: ({} {})>".format(self.id, self.name)

    def is_management(self):
        return self.user_type in [self.USER_EMPLOYEE, self.USER_ADMIN]

    def is_admin(self):
        return self.user_type == self.USER_ADMIN
```

Edit:

I've discovered  that `Base.metadata.sorted_tables` is empty.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In addition to importing your declarative `Base` class, you also need to import all of your models as well. Something like `import project.models` or whatever module(s) you have to include so that all your model classes are imported. Otherwise, your `Base.metadata` doesn't get populated with your model definitions since `env.py` never includes them.

Comment: If you're like me, and already had the table defined, make sure to rename the existing tables e.g. with the `_old` suffix, perform your alembic generate, delete the extra drop statements in the auto-gen script (it will find your renamed tables and generate drop/create statements), and finally rename the tables back.

There should probably be an `--init` option you can pass to auto-generate so that its not this roundabout...